# Как сделать сночоску у блока

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как сделать вот такую сноску у блока?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня сейчас:

```css
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 204px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #FFCC00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(255, 204, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Ссылка #1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Ссылка #2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Ссылка #3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Ссылка #4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 204px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #FFCC00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(255, 204, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 4px 0px 4px 4px;
  z-index: 500;
}
.dropdown:before, .dropdown:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.dropdown:before{
  right: -1px;
  top: -11px;
  border: 5px solid;
  border-color: transparent #FFCC00 #FFCC00 transparent;
}
.dropdown:after{
  right: 0;
  top: -8px;
  border: 4px solid;
  border-color: transparent #fff #fff transparent;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!